# Why do many frameworks use 1400-1600px for their XXL breakpoint?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, breakpoints

## Background

I apologize in advance if this is an unusual question.

I am working on a site where I had to configure a set of breakpoints. I struggled figuring out what size I should make my breakpoints, so I based mine approximately on [Bootstrap's breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/). Furthermore, I did some digging and found that many frameworks / projects use similar breakpoints, including Tailwind.

#### Bootstrap 5's Breakpoints

```scss
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1400px
);
```

## Question

So my question is why do so many projects use an XXL breakpoint size around 1400-1600px when the majority of desktop monitors are much larger today?

## Purpose of Question

Most monitors have come in 1920px for nearly 20 years, and many new monitors are 2560px or larger. I am finding that my 1920px monitor already maxes out the XXL breakpoint, so I can't change the style on larger screens without creating even larger breakpoints.

Just to clarify, I am not looking for an "opinion" about what breakpoint sizes to use. I have seen many projects that use sizes similar to this, so I am compelled to believe they probably know what they're doing and I'm just using the breakpoints incorrectly.

My end goal is to determine if I should define larger breakpoints for 2k, 4k, or if 1400-1600px is enough for the larger screens and I just need to change the way I am using them.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14894

Comment: Fun-fact: you don't need CSS breakpoints. It's entirely possible to design a layout using modern CSS features (like flex and grid, especially grid's repeating auto-columns feature) that gracefully reflows for small handheld UIs right up to large desktops.

Comment: I speculate, but one possible reason for using 1600px at the high-end is because on a wide enough monitor (such as 1920px) users tend to stop viewing pages full-screen and instead multi-task with multiple overlapping or tiling windows (and `1600x1200px` was often the highest resolution anyone could get (without paying $2000+ for a monitor) back in the days of CRTs (In 2007 I briefly had a pair of 22-inch LaCie Electron Blue IV CRTs (from eBay, no way I could afford them new!) and ostensibly they could do 1920x1440px but analogue signals really don't work that well.

Comment: What psychopath is looking at websites in a 2500+ px wide window? Most websites are mostly whitespace at that size anyway. Use your available real estate better, even if it’s just to look at your wallpaper instead of a website’s whitespace.

Comment: @deceze I will say that it does make sense to have a window open full-screen on a huge monitor (like my current 4K 43-inch Dell (at 96dpi!)) for viewing spreadsheets, dashboards, and various forms of _mass data_ (including when those are accessed via a web browser) - but yeah, ["normal" websites are often unusable due to unthinking web designers who assume everyone uses portrait-orientation mobile browsers](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/content-dispersion/) \*le sigh\*

Comment: @Dai Agreed, data heavy sites can soak up as much real estate as is available. But the average text-only site like SO, text can’t be stretched much wider than 100 characters per line before it becomes unreadable, so most websites are vertical anyway. Which is in fact why I have a vertical monitor, which actually makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I remember using breakpoints like 20 years ago. I agree with @DaiThe general rule now is, you stretch your width until the page looks like ###. That is your break point.